# passing args to threading.Thread to a CLASS without override class self?

Tags: python, class, plotly, init, figure

Pretty sure that this should be a simple noob thing or a conceptual confusion of mine but I am not seeing it. Context: I need to do several focused plotly figures from a HUGE figure (used as base figure) and save it on separate html files. So I planned to load de huge figure just once in a class **init** and then thread args to a second class function that makes the work of setting limits and saving fig to html.

In theory (I guess) everything should be fine but when a pass the args to the target thread the first argument passed overrides the self local var of class that contains the huge figure to cut. So, how do I have to pass the args to avoid this overriding issue???. Any suggestions??. Simplified example:

´´´
import threading

```
 class Map ():
  def __init__(self):
         self.fig = load('HugeFig')

 def second (self,arg1,arg2):
         self.fig.show()            %here I set limit but show() exemplifies
                                    %the issue that is reading the '_' from thread args. I 
                                     %thought use self to access self.fig but error : str has no fig 

class Main ():
  def run () :
     Map()                                              % calls the class to load HUGE figure only once.

     threat = threading.Thread(target=Map.second,args=(_,arg1,arg2))

if __name__ == "__main__":

     Main.run()
```

´´´

Comment: what kind of object is `load('HugeFig')` ?

Comment: just loading a plotly figure ... huge superficial map ... I loaded from a static file through pickle = pickle.load(open('iHugeFig, 'rb')) ... and gets loaded well, I checked ...

Comment: you should create instance `my_map = Map()` and later use `tager=my_map.second` and it will run at `Map.second(my_map, your_args)` and it will assing `my_map` to `self`. If you use `Map.second` then it doesn't know that it has to assign instance to `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply use class in wrong way.

You have to assign object/instance to variable `my_map = Map()`
and later use this variable `target=my_map.second` instead of `target=Map.second`.

And use `args` without `_` - it will automatically assign `my_map` to `self`

```
def run () :
    my_map = Map()

    threat = threading.Thread(target=my_map.second, args=(arg1, arg2))
```

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. As I suspected was a noob error. Furthermore, I figured out that my initial idea was not going to work because when I create a copy of the HUGE fig to set small limits map for a new lighter file, that copy inherits all the data from Huge Fig, and the resulting file it's heavy also ... I'm going to create a new question to find if somebody knows how to erase data outside de new limits to generate lighter files.